# Why isn't the background image appearing on IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, xhtml

The background image doesn't appear in IE8, but it works fine in all browsers, including IE9

Relevant CSS:

```
    #player {
      background: url('/images/tv-screen.jpg') center top repeat-x;
      padding: 25px 26px 0 -1px;
      width: 660px;
      height: 403px;
      border: #555 solid 1px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

Relevant HTML:

```
     <p id="player">...//some data ..</p>
```

Comment: <p id="player">...//some data ..</p> ending quoats  missing

Comment: @Muhammad shetos : sometime there is a very tiny prob just try it before everythig=ng ...... put url('../images/tv-screen.jpg') in place of url('/images/tv-screen.jpg')

Comment: its not the problem I write it wrong :)

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid: even the folder images in the root

Comment: if u havent tried then u should , but if u have tried then let us know

Comment: yes I tried and also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is : there is iframe inside iframe which blocking the background I don't know why , even I make the two iframe with wmode=transparent.

so I created a background in last iframe by js in IE less than 9 only.

thanks guys for your time .

Answer (score 2):

The CSS looks okay.

I think IE8 fails on the tag itself: `<p id="player>`. The id attribute doesn't have a closing `"`. If this causes the id to be misinterpreted, the CSS selector will 
not match it.

Answer (score 1):

are you using the correct DOCTYPE ?

http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the negative padding that you have set. This can cause issues in ie7/8.